# Oracle database error 12514: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: mysql, oracle, tableau-api

Now I am using Tableau business intelligence tool for data visualization,i tried to connect Oracle database with tableau,at that time i got below Error'

```
 Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that 
 you have access privileges to the requested database.

 Oracle database error 12514: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently 
  know of service requested in connect descriptor

 Unable to connect to the Oracle server "192.176.10.145". Check that the 
 server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested 
database.
```

in what mistake i did,kindly help me out ,give any suggestion to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/troubleshooting-oracle-connection-errors#listener1) from tableau which suggests that the ORA-12514 error occurs when SERVICE value is incorrect.

> To resolve this issue, find out what the correct SERVICE value is, open the TNSNames.ora file located in your %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\ folder. Refer to the steps under ORA_12154 if necessary.

Comment: i will try and let you know,thanks for your response,if the question is valid one please aprriciate with your upvote @Daniel Sims

Comment: Appreciated. Just a quick note - the error in your title name differs from that in the error message.

Comment: yes corrected title,and your answer is correct,thank you @Daniel Sims